# Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers. NUXT

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt and nuxt-vuex-localstorage
When i change a item from v-for and it element is inside store i get an error...

```
<v-btn
              @click="addCurrentProduct( subItem)"
              v-if="!subItem.carrito"
              color="green"
              dark
              >Agregar</v-btn
            >
            <v-row v-if="subItem.carrito">
              <v-btn @click="subItem.cantidadCarrito--,removeProduct(subItem)" color="green" icon dark>
                <v-icon>mdi-minus-circle-outline</v-icon></v-btn
              >
              <span>{{
                subItem.cantidadCarrito
              }}</span>
              <v-btn @click="subItem.cantidadCarrito++,addProduct(subItem)" color="green" icon dark>
                <v-icon>mdi-plus-circle-outline</v-icon></v-btn
              >
            </v-row>
```

```
methods: {
    addCurrentProduct( product) {
      product.cantidadCarrito++;
      product.carrito = true;
      console.log("error")
      let temp=product
      this.$store.commit("localStorage/Sum_Cantidad");
      this.$store.commit("localStorage/ADD_PRODUCT", temp);


    },
addProduct(producto) {
      var temp = this.buscar(producto);   
      producto.carrito = true;   

      this.$store.commit("localStorage/ReNew_PRODUCTO", {
        index: temp,
        producto: producto
      });

      this.$store.commit("localStorage/Sum_Cantidad");
    }
```

I have error in subItem.cantidadCarrito++, i think that they are connected with Vuex store (Nuxt) and when i change it element, the element is inside of vuex also change and i get it error

Comment: Make a copy of the object using the spread operator. var newObject = {...product, carrito: true, cantidadCarrito++}

Comment: I don't understand... if i do it, i lost my data when i reload... i have got it mistake when i a click on the button addproduct, before it all good, addCurrentProduct is working good, and then no... it's the same method, idk what are happening

Comment: You can use getters/setters if you'd like to maintain reactivity with objects from the store.

Comment: I'm using nuxt...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, changing it inside  vuex store from localstorage, when i put a item for first time, this element automatically is join with the localstorage and i can't do any change outside from local.